# Inserting data into multiple tables through an sql view

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there any way to insert data into multiple tables through a view in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL Reference Manual says this about updatable views:

> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such as `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` to update the contents of the underlying table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a **one-to-one relationship** between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.
>
> The `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause can be given for an updatable view to prevent inserts or updates to rows except those for which the `WHERE` clause in the select_statement is true. The `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause was implemented in MySQL 5.0.2.

You can find the entire article [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 1):

See [this piece](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html) of MySQL reference manual:

> It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable,
>   assuming that it can be processed with the MERGE algorithm. For this
>   to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a
>   UNION). Also, only a single table in the view definition can be
>   updated, so the SET clause must name only columns from one of the
>   tables in the view. Views that use UNION ALL are not permitted even
>   though they might be theoretically updatable, because the
>   implementation uses temporary tables to process them.
>
> For a multiple-table updatable view, INSERT can work if it inserts
>   into a single table. DELETE is not supported.
>
> INSERT DELAYED is not supported for views.