# Can I INSERT/UPDATE into two tables with one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a chunk of the SQL I'm using for a Perl-based web application. I have a number of requests and each has a number of accessions, and each has a status. This chunk of code is there to update the table for every accession_analysis that shares all these fields for each accession in a request.

```
UPDATE accession_analysis
SET analysis_id = ? ,
    reference_id = ? ,
    status = ? , 
    extra_parameters = ?
WHERE analysis_id = ?
AND reference_id = ?
AND status = ?
AND extra_parameters = ?
and accession_id is (
    SELECT accesion_id
    FROM accessions
    where request_id = ?
    )
```

I have changed the tables so that there's a status table for accession_analysis, so when I update, I update both accession_analysis and accession_analysis_status, which has status, status_text and the id of the accession_analysis, which is a not null auto_increment variable.

I have no strong idea about how to modify this code to allow this. My first pass grabbed all the accessions and looped through them, then filtered for all the fields, then updated. I didn't like that because I had many connections with short SQL commands, which I understood to be bad, but I can't help but think the only way to really do this is to go back to the loop in Perl holding two simpler SQL statements.

Is there a way to do this in SQL that, with my relative SQL inexperience, I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on which DBMS you're using. The easiest way is to create a trigger on one table that provides the logic of updating the other table. (For any DB newbies -- a trigger is procedural code attached to a table at the DBMS (not application) layer that runs in response to an insert, update or delete on the table.). A similar, slightly less desirable method is to put the logic in a stored procedure and execute that instead of the update statement you're now using.

If the DBMS you're using doesn't support either of these mechanisms, then there isn't a good way to do what you're after while guaranteeing transactional integrity. However if the problem you're solving can tolerate a timing difference in the two tables' updates (i.e. The data in one of the tables is only used at predetermined times, like reporting or some type of batched operation) you could write to one table (live) and create a separate process that runs when needed (later) to update the second table using data from the first table. The correctness of allowing data to be updated at different times becomes a large and immovable design assumption, however.

Comment: While I don't agree on the desireability ;-) A trigger may be a good idea, too if the system remains maintainable afterwards...

Comment: Good description of solutions, but learning to do stored procedures and triggers seems like a long solution. I'm implementing this via loops in Perl and putting "Learn Stored Procedures and Triggers in MySQL" onto my to-do list.

Answer (score 2):

If this is mostly about connection speed, then one option you have is to write a stored procedure that handles the "double update or insert" transparently. See the manual for stored procedures:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html

Otherwise, You probably cannot do it in one statement, see the MySQL `INSERT` syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

The `UPDATE` syntax allows for multi-table updates (not in combination with `INSERT`, though):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

**Each table needs its own `INSERT` / `UPDATE` in the query.**

In fact, even if you create a view by `JOIN`ing multiple tables, when you `INSERT` into the view, you can only `INSERT` with fields belonging to one of the tables at a time.

> The modifications made by the INSERT statement cannot affect more than one of the base tables referenced in the FROM clause of the view. For example, an INSERT into a multitable view must use a column_list that references only columns from *one* base table. For more information about updatable views, see CREATE VIEW.

- [Inserting data into multiple tables through an sql view (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919258/inserting-data-into-multiple-tables-through-an-sql-view/2919316#2919316)
- [INSERT (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Same is true of `UPDATE`

> The modifications made by the UPDATE statement *cannot affect more than one* of the base tables referenced in the FROM clause of the view. For more information on updatable views, see CREATE VIEW.

However, you can have multiple `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s per query or stored procedure.